# Squid Windows maxfiledescriptors

Tags: windows, squid

We have problems with squid in Windows Server running out of maxfiledescriptors and hanging. When we launch squid although in config file we have the value 4092 for maxfiledescriptors it only takes 3200 (the value of the system operating). Is there any way to increase maxfiledescriptors in Windwos in order squid works.

Best Regards.

Solution from experts

Comment: Are you looking for a solution by changing the Squid configuration or by changing the Squid source code and rebuilding then running your unofficial fork (and merging your change into every future version/update)?  Configuration questions would belong on ServerFault (and you should give specific details of what configuration setting you changed)